# How to connect to local SQL Server database from another pc

Tags: sql-server, database, tcp

I've set a up a small SQL Server database on my laptop, I would like to access it from my Desktop PC, I'm a bit confused.

I've already Enabled TCP/IP protocols from SQL Server Configuration Mnagement, and I've already opened a port on the Windows Firewall and enabled remote connection on the database i want to connect to and added a login account to use for the connection.

From my desktop's SQLServer Managent instance,I've tried putting as ServerName, both the name I see on my laptop, (which I guess it's the local name of the machine) and the public IP adress + port, but nothing happens.

How do I get  the two computers to communicate?

Comment: What does "nothing happens" mean? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Are both machines on the same domain? Can you ping your laptop?

Comment: What do you mean by "public IP"? Normally public IP means the IP others would use to access your domain/location externally; i.e. your IP address of your router on the internet. Are the 2 devices not on the same network? If so, you'll need to configure port forwarding and firewall rules to limit who can connect on your router too.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for answering me so quickly. Your questions made me realize I was using the wrong IP, I used a public IP I found through one of those tracking websites. Instead I should have used the "IPv4 adress" i found on my wi-fi internet settings. Now it works I can connect to my laptop's database and query the data. Thank you very much,